# Justify content doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

im starting to learn html5 & css3 by myself but have troubles centering elements with justify-content. My goal is make a basic responsive layout.

In my code I have the whole web centered but can't get the divs inside the header centered as well. Im trying to use "justify-content" setting it to center and Flex to 1 since I want my 3 divs use the total space in the navigator but it doesn't works. So if anybody could help me that would be great. Thanks!

PD: Sorry if my english is not very good.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>HTML5</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="element1">ELEMENT 1</div>
        <div id="element2">ELEMENT 2</div>
        <div id="element3">ELEMENT 3</div>          
    </header>
    <section>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
    display:block;
}
html{
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    height:100%;    
}
body {
    max-width:2000px;
    display:flex;
    margin:auto;
    background:gray;
}
header{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
header div{
    padding:10px;
    flex:1;
}
#element1{
    background:yellow;
}
#element2{
    background:red;
}
#element3{
    background:orange;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this :

```
header {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thx it works! Just a little question, im curious because i try it without justify-content and works, it means justify-content is not necessary in this case? in which case is necessary?

Comment: it's because the header is only as wide as its content in your case. You can give the header a 100% percent width and the divs a flex: 0 0 auto; value and the justify-content: center will work as expected....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add additional container for divs in header section.
Then set it to be displayed as inline-block. Last step is to set "text-align" property of header to center.
Code: https://jsfiddle.net/8w3rz77o/

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
    display:block;
}
html{
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    height:100%;    
}
body {
    max-width:2000px;
    background:gray;
    width: 100%;
}
header{
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
header > div{
      display: inline-block;
}
header > div > div{
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#element1{
    background:yellow;
}
#element2{
    background:red;
}
#element3{
    background:orange;
    }
```